# recyclerview jumps to top on paging in android

Tags: android, pagination, mvp

In MVP pattern, I have a list that fetched from server by retrofit, while implementation pagination, my infinteScrollListener just return the fixed page number and the list jumps to top.

my code is below:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_list);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    listAdapter = new ProductListAdapter(this);
    mPresenter.start();

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent != null) {
        mostTitle = intent.getStringExtra(TOPBENEFIT);
        mostStatus.setText(mostTitle);

        code = intent.getIntExtra(MOST_ITEMS_CODE, -1);


        mPresenter.getAllTopBenefitgetAllTopBenefitFirst(currentPage, "", "", ADD_ONLY_IF_LIST_IS_EMPTY);
        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    }


}



@Override
public void showAllTopBenefitProducts(List<ResponseAllProductList> list, ProductListAdapter.AddStrategy strategy) {
    listAdapter.addList(list, strategy);

    recyclerProductsList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);


    recyclerProductsList.addOnScrollListener(new InfiniteScrollListener(linearLayoutManager) {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int current_page) {
            currentPage++;
            mPresenter.getMostItemsCode(code, current_page, brandId, search, ADD_PAGINATION_ITEMS);
        }
    });


    recyclerProductsList.setAdapter(listAdapter);

}
```

my infinite scroll listener class:

public abstract class InfiniteScrollListener extends 
RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {

```
public static String TAG = InfiniteScrollListener.class.getSimpleName();
int firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;
private int previousTotal = 0;
private boolean loading = true;
private int visibleThreshold = 2;
private int current_page = 1;

private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;

public InfiniteScrollListener(LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager) {
    this.mLinearLayoutManager = linearLayoutManager;
}

@Override
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

    visibleItemCount = recyclerView.getChildCount();
    totalItemCount = mLinearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
    firstVisibleItem = mLinearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

    if (loading) {
        if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
            loading = false;
            previousTotal = totalItemCount;
        }
    }
    if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount - firstVisibleItem <= visibleThreshold)) {

        int a = current_page + 1;

        onLoadMore(a);


        loading = true;
    }
}

public void resetState() {
    loading = true;
    previousTotal = 0;
    current_page = 1;
}

public abstract void onLoadMore(int current_page);
```

}

Comment: instead of reinventing the wheel, use google's [paging](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html) support library